# Implementing Two-Legged Oauth2 in ZendFramework 2 with Apigility

Tags: api, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, zend-framework2

I am trying to build a ZendFramework2 Rest API and want to implement two-legged OAuth2 authentication.

I have been looking around and can not find any resources to help point me in the right direction with this.

Has anyone done this before or know of a good source I am missing?

Comment: Have you read the docs here -> https://apigility.org/documentation/auth/authentication-oauth2

Comment: @Crisp I've been looking around that documentation for a while, I am relatively new to oauth and am trying to test with postman in chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `OAuth` you can make access tokens client specific by assigning a `client_id`.
This `client_id` can be stored in some local storage on the client side and reused on the next user login from that client.

When the user logs in first time from a new client (no `client_id` in the storage for this user) then a new `client_id` is created and some 2nd verification step can be added to this part of the authentication process. For example sending an text message to his phone number. You could add an `expires_at` field to the client table so that you can repeat this process if the `client_id` has expired.

Comment: thanks for the answer, after doing more research over the weekend I have come up with my issue.. I was trying to compare oauth1 simple authentication to oauth2 2-3 legged. I appreciate your answer and as it helped me understand oauth a little more I will mark it so